# My search in python using tree view is not working/displaying the search results

Tags: python, tkinter, search, treeview

This is my two functions which operate my search. The problem seems to occur with my search function when I binded it to my key releases on my search entries. However when I search with my button it works with no error messages .

```
        def SearchCustomer(self):
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Guestrecord.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            columnID = ["title","firstName","surname","dob","payment","email","address","postcode"]
            columnStr =["Title","FirstName","Surname","DOB","Payment","Email","Address","Postcode"]

            self.search_table = ttk.Treeview(self.search_frame,columns=columnID,show="headings")

            self.search_table.bind("<Motion>","break")

            for i in range(0,8):
                self.search_table.heading(columnID[i],text = columnStr[i])
                self.search_table.column(columnID[i],minwidth = 0, width = 108)
            self.search_table.place(x=20,y=0)

            for GuestRec in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tb1Guest1"):
                self.search_table.insert("",END,values=GuestRec)

            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
        SearchCustomer(self)

        

        search_icon = Image.open("search icon.png")
        search_icon_resize = search_icon.resize((20,20))
        search_icon = search_icon_resize
        search_icon_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(search_icon)


        self.search_firstname = Entry(self.search_frame2, width=30,bg="#e2f0d9",font=("Avenir Next",18),highlightthickness = 0,relief=FLAT)
        self.search_firstname.place(x = 140, y =0)
        self.search_firstname_label = Label(self.search_frame2,bg = "white", text = "First Name", font=("Avenir Next",20))
        self.search_firstname_label.place(x= 20,y=0)
        self.search_Surname = Entry(self.search_frame2, width=30,bg="#e2f0d9",font=("Avenir Next",18),highlightthickness = 0,relief=FLAT)
        self.search_Surname.place(x = 140, y =40)
        self.search_Surname_label = Label(self.search_frame2,bg = "white", text = "Surname", font=("Avenir Next",20))
        self.search_Surname_label.place(x= 20,y=40)
        searchButton = Button(self.search_frame2, image=search_icon_photo,height = 35, width =35, command=self.Search,bg ="white")
        searchButton.place(x= 500, y = 0)


##      Binding entries
        self.search_firstname.bind("<KeyRelease>",self.Search)
        self.search_Surname.bind("<KeyRelease>",self.Search)
      

    def Search(self):

        sFirst_Name = self.search_firstname.get()
        sSurname = self.search_Surname.get()
        search_rec = (sFirst_Name,sSurname)

        search_rec_new = tuple(item for item in search_rec if item !="")
        search_fields = ["guestFirstname","guestFirstname"]

        search_SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb1Guest1 WHERE guestID LIKE '%'"

        for i in range(len(search_rec)):
            if search_rec[i] != "":
                 search_SQL += " AND " + search_fields[i] + " LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"

        connection = sqlite3.connect("Guestrecord.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        # Clearing search results
        for rec in self.search_table.get_children():
            self.search_table.delete(rec)

        #Display the records 

        for GuestRec in cursor.execute(search_SQL,search_rec_new):
            self.search_table.insert("",END,values=GuestRec)

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

Then this is the message which pops up when I try to type in my search entries:

It may have something to do with my .self but I don't know how I would over come this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Main_menu.Search() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If someone could provide a solution to my problem it would be great as I have spend seemingly a lot of time trying to figure this error out.

Answer (score 0):

The function for a binding event expects an argument: the `Event` object.  However you also use the same function for a button command which does not expect that extra argument.

So you need to add an optional argument to `Search()`:

```py
# event argument is optional, if not provided, it will be None
def Search(self, event=None):
    ...
```